# How to Use PrependTo Dynamically on each Element

Tags: html, jquery

I have a requirement where an element with a particular class has to be prepended to its sibling with another class. Although I am able to achieve this for the first instance, it doesn't work for all the elements in the div. I have tried the below code

[Click Here](https://jsfiddle.net/8r2jpdmL/5/)

```
This Works:
$("#MyDiv .spanToBeShifted:first").prependTo($("#MyDiv .MyButton:first"));


This Doesnt:
$("#MyDiv .spanToBeShifted").prependTo($(this).closest('.MyButton'))
```

Comment: Your link is broken. Please take some effort to include your code here. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry for that. Its working now

Answer (score 0):

Below is the solution which worked for me

[Solution](https://jsfiddle.net/1fqga2mx/1/)

```
$('.spanToBeShifted').each(function () {
    var d = $(this).siblings('.MyButton');
    
    $(this).prependTo(d)
});
```